# How to read Excel cell having Date with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 3.6, I want to read an excel file which has a date like this `8/23/1991`.

```
 switch (cell.getCellType()) {

   ...
   ...

   case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     value = "NUMERIC value=" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
     break;

   ...

 }
```

But it takes the numeric value type and returns the value like this `33473.0`.

I've tried to use Numeric Cell Type although with no luck.

```
dbltemp=row.getCell(c, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getNumericCellValue();

if (c == 6 || c == 9) {
    strTemp= new String(dbltemp.toString().trim());

    long tempDate = Long.parseLong(strTemp);
    Date date = new Date(tempDate);

    strVal = date.toString();
}
```

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: For my pet project, I changed it to a **Text** column in the excel sheet to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**NOTE: HSSFDateUtil is deprecated**

If you know which cell i.e. column position say 0 in each row is going to be a date, you can go for 
`row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue()` directly.
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getDateCellValue()

UPDATE: Here is an example - you can apply this in your switch case code above. I am checking and printing the Numeric as well as Date value. In this case the first column in my sheet has dates, hence I use row.getCell(0).

You can use the `if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted ..` code block directly in your switch case.

```
if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    System.out.println ("Row No.: " + row.getRowNum ()+ " " +
        row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());

    if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(row.getCell(0))) {
        System.out.println ("Row No.: " + row.getRowNum ()+ " " + 
            row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Row No.: 0 39281.0
Row No.: 0 Wed Jul 18 00:00:00 IST 2007
Row No.: 1 39491.0
Row No.: 1 Wed Feb 13 00:00:00 IST 2008
Row No.: 2 39311.0
Row No.: 2 Fri Aug 17 00:00:00 IST 2007
```

Comment: I can't get any values... If you could specify a code snippet, that would be great...

Comment: Calling DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted() will be a step ahead in the way of freeing your code from HSSFs and XSSFs. By using global parents instead of XLS/XLSX dependant HSSF/XSSF children, you can make your code much universal.

Comment: Please, adjust or remove the second link. It is returning 404 error.

Comment: This is tricky because isCellDateFormatted should also apply to CELL_TYPE_FORMULA as long it is a Date formula. If you try to call on a text formula an IllegalStateException is thrown

Comment: I get Mon Apr 03 10:12:14 CEST 2017, you got for example with IST. How would I know the format is always the same? so I then can re-format it in Java.

Comment: @powder366: i havent checked this recently,but as this returns a `java.util.Date` this will be in the local time zone of the user and can be formatted using standard api

Comment: What's the difference between DateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumericCellValue()) and cell.getDateCellValue()?

Comment: Is there any information on the actual meaning of that cell value?

Comment: HSSFDateUtil is deprecated in version 4.1.2

Comment: Instead of `HSSFDateUtil`, just use `DateUtil` (parent class of `HSSFDateUtil`)

Comment: Instead of HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC use CellType.NUMERIC

Answer (score 25):

Yes, I understood your problem.
If is difficult to identify cell has Numeric or Data value.

If you want data in format that shows in Excel, you just need to format cell using DataFormatter class.

```
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
String cellStringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0));
System.out.println ("Is shows data as show in Excel file" + cellStringValue);  // Here it automcatically format data based on that cell format.
// No need for extra efforts
```

Comment: How to get it formatted in ISO format? (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: It shows numbers always.

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;


Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC||cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA)
   {
    

 String cellValue=String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
     if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
      {
          DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
          Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
          cellValue = df.format(date);
       }
          System.out.println(cellValue);
    }
```

Comment: Please add more context to your answer. Just writing code as an answer might not be that clear for everybody who is reading your answer.

Comment: It uses getDateCellValue as other answers here, but also uses SimpleDateFormat to format the Date value which is something that most users would want

Answer (score 4):

Apache Poi has a DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(XSSFCell) it works great.

```
Object objData = switch (cell.getCellType()){
   case NUMERIC ->{
      if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
         yield cell.getDateCellValue();
      }else{
         yield cell.getNumericCellValue();
      }
  } //The rest of the cellTypes need to be implemented.
}
```

objData can now be tested for Date or Double.

Answer (score 2):

For reading date cells this method has proven to be robust so far:

```
private LocalDate readCellAsDate(final Row row, final int pos) {
    if (pos == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    final Cell cell = row.getCell(pos - 1);
    if (cell != null) {
        cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        try {
            return cell.getDateCellValue().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the DateUtils: see [this article](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html) for details.

Or, better yet, use Andy Khan's JExcel instead of POI.

Comment: I've almost implemented many things in POI, I'm so sorry that I can't go for any just for this.. There must be something.. Yet, Thank you duffymo

Comment: DateUtils will sort you out if you can't switch to JExcel

Comment: That link is dead, though still reachable by [WayBack](https://web.archive.org/web/20180227200112/http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html). Even so, I don't see any mention of DateUtils.

Comment: I suppose, HSSFDateUtil was meant by DateUtil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CellDateFormatter to fetch the Date in the same format as in excel cell. See the following code:

```
CellValue cv = formulaEv.evaluate(cell);
double dv = cv.getNumberValue();
if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(dv);

    String df = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();

    strValue = new CellDateFormatter(df).format(date); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the cell number, then i would recommend using getDateCellValue() method
Here's an example for the same that worked for me - 
java.util.Date date  = row.getCell().getDateCellValue();
System.out.println(date);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(result));
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Iterate through each rows one by one
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        // For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (cell.getNumericCellValue() != 0) {
                    //Get date
                    Date date = row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue();



                    //Get datetime
                    cell.getDateCellValue()


                    System.out.println(date.getTime());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope is help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void readExcel() {
        try {
            String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
            File file = new File(path + "/myexcelsheet.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rowIter = sheet.iterator();
            int rowno = 1;
            if (rowno !=0){
                while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIter.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    textView4.append("\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.getRowNum(); i++) {
                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:    //field that represents string cell type
                                    textView4.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "" + "\t\t" + "");

                                break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:    //field that represents number cell type
                                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                        Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                                        textView4.append(dateFormat.format(date) + "" + "\t\t" + "");
                                    }else{
                                        textView4.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "" + "\t\t" + "");
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                            textView4.append("");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```