# Error: "Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell", when converting Excel

Tags: java, excel

I have excel sheet with date column, when I run my program I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
```

My code that I run:

```
String date =sheets.getRow(choosenRow).getCell(3).getStringCellValue().toString();
```

How can I convert numeric value to String? in my case I used `.toString();` but seems it didn't worked.

Comment: What is the type of the number? a double? or an int?

Comment: [It's documented behavior](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue--): "*For numeric cells we throw an exception.*". Use `getNumericCellValue()`, then convert the `double` to a `String`

Comment: @PieterMantel in Excel the format is short date

Comment: @VinceEmigh didn't work

Comment: @mona You'll have to provide more context, such as the sheet you're working with. The error states that your cell is numeric. You could try `getDateCellValue()` if you're suggesting the cell is a date value.

Comment: @mona if `getNumericCellValue` did not work as you said, why accepting an answer which propose only it ? And not the one giving a solution to deal with date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is because you are using `.getStringCellValue()`, when you should be using `getNumericCellValue()`. `.getStringCellValue()` can't be used with NUMERIC cells. I'm assuming that you are using Apache POI by the way.

See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html for more info.

I'm not sure why I was downvoted, can you let me know in the comments about how I can rewrite it to be more clear(if that is the problem) or tell me how it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i not tested your code..!

but

you should try `Object` class to get data from that exal file. if data are successfully recevied. then you can convert in to date or String.

like :

```
Object objdata = sheets.getRow(choosenRow).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, it's working perfectly now. I have changed the code to be like that:

```
Date date =sheets.getRow(choosenRow).getCell(3)getDateCellValue();
dateTextField.setText(""+date);
```

Answer (score -1):

The error tells you that the cell if type `NUMERIC`, you may use the approriate method `getNumericCellValue()`

```
String date = "" + sheets.getRow(choosenRow).getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
```

---

If you don't know the type before, and need to read some values, you may implment a `switch` on the type (`getCellType()`) and from the result of this enum  use the right method

Specifically for the numeric type, you can check for date element :

```
public String getContent(Cell c){
    switch(c.getCellType()){
        case: NONE     :  throw new IllegalArgumentException("NONE");
        case: BLANK    :  return "";
        case: BOOLEAN  :  return ""+c.getBooleanCellValue();
        case: ERROR    :  return ""+c.getErrorCellValue()
        case: FORMULA  :  return c.getCellFormula()
        case: NUMERIC  :  return HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(c)) ? 
                                 c.getDateCellValue()) : ""+c.getNumericCellValue();
        case: STRING   :  return c.getStringCellValue()
}
```

Ref to [***How to read Excel cell having Date with Apache POI?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148535/how-to-read-excel-cell-having-date-with-apache-poi)