# Cannot read all rows in Excel - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am able to read the values in a first sheet, but not in [the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVzNf.png).

Well I am not an experienced in Java, and this is a very strange problem that I've been having.

I am trying to get values of columns corresponding to rows in an Excel file.

I am able to get the values in the first sheet properly.

However, in [the second sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVzNf.png), when I try to read all rows, it gives me a `rowcount` value of `1`, although there are two rows of data.

In my method, I am passing the `key` and the `column` values to get the corresponding data. It works for the first sheet i.e. `account`, but does not work for [the second sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVzNf.png)'s `employee`.

Below is the method that I am using to read the Excel file using a `ConfigurationFile` Reader, and then put those values in a `Map`, and then call the method to read the cell values:

```java
package TestFramework;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestExcel {


    public static Map<String, Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    public static void readExcel(String fileName, String sheetName) throws IOException {
        ConfigFileReader config = new ConfigFileReader();
        String excelFilePath = config.getDataModelPath();
        //Create an object of File class to open xlsx file
        File file = new File(excelFilePath);
        //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook myWorkbook = null;
        //Find the file extension by splitting file name in substring  and getting only extension name
        String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));
        //Check condition if the file is xlsx file
        if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")) {
            //If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class
            myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }
        //Check condition if the file is xls file
        else if (fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")) {
            //If it is xls file then create object of HSSFWorkbook class
            myWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        }

        //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name
        Sheet excelSheet = myWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        //Find number of rows in excel file
        int rowCount = excelSheet.getLastRowNum() - excelSheet.getFirstRowNum();

        Row header = null;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount + 1; rowIndex++) {
            // if first row, save as header
            if (rowIndex == 0) {
                header = excelSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            } else {
                Row currentRow = excelSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                Map<String,String> rowCells = new HashMap<>();
                String outerKey = null;
                // else, read row cells; for each cell, get corresponding header
                // and save in map
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < rowCount + 1; colIndex++) {
                    if (colIndex == 0) {
                        outerKey = currentRow.getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();
                    } else {
                        String key = header.getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();
                        String cellValue = currentRow.getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();
                        rowCells.put(key, cellValue);
                    }
                }
                map.put(outerKey, rowCells);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getValueFromExcel(String rowKey, String columnKey) throws IOException {
        return map.get(rowKey).get(columnKey);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader();
        String fileName1 = "Test.xlsx";
        String sheetName1 = "employee";
        readExcel(fileName1,sheetName1);
        String firstName = getValueFromExcel("emp_A","first_name");
        String lastName = getValueFromExcel("emp_A","last_name");
        //String lastName = reader.getValueFromExcel(string,"last_name");
        String fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }

}
```

When I read the second sheet, the row count always seems to be 1. Although when I delete the first sheet and keep only the second sheet, I am able to get the values propetly. Just cant figure out where I am making the mistake.

---

Below is an my second sheet in Excel.
(*The first one looks the same just with different values.*)

[image: second Excel sheet]

Comment: You could use `for(Row row : excelSheet){for(Cell cell : row){}}` to iterate all rows and columns in the excel sheet

Comment: this instruction stops for cycle based on rowCount? for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < rowCount + 1; colIndex++) {

Comment: post a representation of your second sheet please

Comment: `int rowCount = excelSheet.getLastRowNum() - excelSheet.getFirstRowNum(); ... for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount + 1; rowIndex++) { ...` is logically wrong. What if sheet's first row number is 5 and sheet's last row number is 9?  Then row count is 4 and your loop goes from row 0 to row 4 but those rows are not present at all. Your loop should be `for (int rowIndex = excelSheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowIndex < excelSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; rowIndex++) { ...`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I tried using getting the cells inside the rows earlier but it did not work for me.

Comment: @Axel Richter as shown in the excel file, I just want to send the name of the Key value = emp_A and column value = first_name to get the corresponding value = Xyz and so on. I am able to retrieve all rows in this particular sheet. For the other sheet, the method that I had implemented works just fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148535/how-to-read-excel-cell-having-date-with-apache-poi

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine using xls extension

Comment: try to check which values you receive for first and last row. and again, this code can't work: colIndex < rowCount + 1

Comment: your code works fine for me with both extension, may be there is something wrong with your excel file

Comment: I tried everything mentioned by everyone here. Still not able to figure what's wrong. Decided to move to CSV file instead of Excel