# How to read values from an excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am currently working on a project for my computer science class, and I was trying to figure out how to retrieve and print certain values from a file in excel. Such as, how would I go about printing the integer in column J, row 6?

Better yet, is there a way for me to return the row number of a string in column 1? Such as, if I had a string "Phone" in column 1, could I use a command to return the row number of the first instance of "phone"?

I have looked at other questions, none of which sufficiently answered my own.

Comment: The proper way to go about this is to read the Apache POI user guide, try the tutorials, and run a few experiments. When you have a program that you *think* should be getting the correct value but isn't, then you ask a question about that program on StackOverflow. An answer would not be meaningful if you don't have the basic knowledge of your problem domain.

Comment: The underlying point of a project is that you will be able to learn something new. It might take some time, but it's worth the investment. I would suggest to read the Apache POI documentation, which also has examples (http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html). Like @RealSkeptic said if you have issues, come back with the code which has the error. Happy learning :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read Excel cell having Date with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148535/how-to-read-excel-cell-having-date-with-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go refer to this class file for iterating over an excel file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/users/developer/Documents/myFile.xlsx";

    public void employeesUpload() {
        String fName = "";
        String lName = "";
        String phoneNumber = "";
        String email = "";
        String gender = "";
        String employeeCode = "";

        try {

            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

            int rowIndex = 0;
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                if (rowIndex > 0) {
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                    employeeCode = fName = lName = phoneNumber = email = gender = "";

                    int cellIndex = 0;
                    while (cellIndex <= 5) {

                        Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cellIndex);
                        if (cellIndex == 4) {
                            employeeCode = formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell).trim();
                        }

                        if (cellIndex == 1) {
                            fName = formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell).trim();
                        }

                        if (cellIndex == 2) {
                            lName = formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell).trim();
                        }

                        if (cellIndex == 0) {
                            email = formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell);
                            email = email.trim().toLowerCase();
                        }

                        if (cellIndex == 3) {
                            phoneNumber = formatter.formatCellValue(currentCell).trim();
                        }

                        cellIndex++;
                    }
                    Cell resultCell = currentRow.getCell(7);

                    if (resultCell == null) {
                        resultCell = currentRow.createCell(7);
                    }

                    Cell employementIdCell = currentRow.getCell(8);
                    if (employementIdCell == null) {
                        employementIdCell = currentRow.createCell(8);
                    }

                    if (true) {
                        resultCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        employementIdCell.setCellValue("Success");
                        resultCell.setCellValue(email);

                    } else {
                        resultCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        resultCell.setCellValue("Error");
                    }

                }
                rowIndex++;
            }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Test employeesBulkUpload = new Test();
        employeesBulkUpload.employeesUpload();

    }
}
```

> Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

user  https://github.com/jueyue/easypoi this jar

use annotion to easy read excel

```
public class ExcelImportNewDateTest {

@Test
public void importTest() {
    ImportParams params = new ImportParams();
    params.setTitleRows(1);
    params.setHeadRows(1);
    long start = new Date().getTime();
    List<NewDateEntity> list = ExcelImportUtil.importExcel(
            new File(FileUtilTest.getWebRootPath("import/ExcelNewDateTest.xlsx")), NewDateEntity.class, params);
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime() - start);
    Assert.assertEquals(list.size(), 100);
    System.out.println(list.size());
    System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(list.get(1)));

}
```

}